# How do I build ITK-SNAP?

Tags: qt, vtk, itk

I use ITK 4.3, VTK and Qt on Visual Studio 9. How do I add ITK-SNAP?

I want to know the difference between ITK and ITK-SNAP and what does ITK-SNAP add compared to ITK.

I started working with ITK. Do I need to change my code or can I continue in my project?

Comment: itk-snap appears to use FLTK instead of Qt. Also I did not read what  versions of ITK and vtk were used however since the latest itk-snap was released in December of 2012 I would expect that itk-4.3 to be too new.

Answer (score 1):

SNAP is a software application used to segment structures in 3D medical images. It provides semi-automatic segmentation using active contour methods, as well as manual delineation and image navigation. The software was designed with the audience of clinical and basic science researchers in mind, and emphasis has been placed on having a user-friendly interface and maintaining a limited feature set to prevent feature creep. ITK-SNAP is free software, provided under the General Public License. ITK-SNAP binaries are provided free of charge for academic or commercial use.
This tutorial provides a step by step walkthrough of building ITK-SNAP 2.4.0  from source on Windows. We will be using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for building the application. Make sure you have VS 2010 installed and VS Service Pack 1 as well. (if required) : [Click Here for full tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/akshatbordia0704/compiling-itk-snap)

Answer (score 0):

[ITK](http://www.itk.org/) is abbrevation of Insight Segmentation and Registration **Toolkit** which is open source **library** which provide image processing algorithms to develop your application on different platforms ex python, c++.You can follow this link: http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2012/11/itk-installation-for-msvc.html to build ITK and use that in your application. [ITK-SNAP](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php) It is an open source **software** you can directly install it from here. I think this is solution for all of your questions.